# I want to print pattern of numbers using c program

Tags: c

If n=3,the output is

```
1*2*3

7*8*9

4*5*6
```

If n=5,the output is

```
1*2*3*4*5

11*12*13*14*15

21*22*23*24*25

16*17*18*19*20

6*7*8*9*10
```

CODE:

```
int i, j, a[50][50], k = 1, m = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n; i += 2) {
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    a[i][j] = k;
    k++;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
m = k;
for (i = 1; i <= n; i += 2) {
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    a[i][j] = m;
    m++;
  }
  printf("\n");
}
for (i = 0; i < n; i++) {
  for (j = 0; j < n; j++) {
    printf("%d", a[i][j]);
  }
  printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: What's stopping you from doing it?

Comment: This is not how it works here, please add the code snippet and the problematic output

Comment: show us your effort?

Comment: http://ideone.com/rS3uRF

Comment: @BLUEPIXY Very elegant solution.

Comment: Thank you all for the solutions.as I am new to this site I was unaware that we are supposed to give the code snippets we have been working on... Well my code ws

Answer (score 0):

I am not so good in c language, but i think it will help you.
please have a look, and you can do making some change if any syntax error occurs but logic is clear.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

void printOutput(int n){

int k = ceil(n/2);
int m =1;
int j =1;
int l =k;
int i;
int b;
for(i=1;i<=n;i++){

for(b=m;b<=m+n;b++){
 printf(b);
}
printf("\n");
  if(i<k){
       j= (2*j);
    m =n*j+1;
  } else{
    int z = n-i-1;
     m= n+1 +n*(2)*z;
    l =z-2;

  }
}
}

void main(){
    int input;
    printf("Enter a Value : ");
    scanf(" %d",&input);
    printOutput(input);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int k=1;
int main(){


    int n;
    scanf("%d",&n);

    for(int i=1;i<=n/2+1;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
        if(j!=1&&j!=n+1){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("%d",k);

        k++;    
        }
        printf("\n \n");
        k=k+n;


    }
    k=k-3*n;


        for(int i=1;i<=n/2;i++){
        for(int j=1;j<=n;j++){
        if(j!=1&&j!=n+1){
            printf("*");
        }
        printf("%d",k);

        k++;    
        }
        printf("\n \n");
        k=k-(n/2+1)*n;


    }





}
```

Answer (score -1):

This is a rough sketch of what you should do, there are some minor flaws with it... However, the functionality is there. Next time, if you can't understand what algorithm the code calls for, I suggest you write this array out on a sheet of paper and follow each row. Notice where each row gets placed, you should start to come up with a way to do this (there are more ways than this one...) It may seem hard at first, but if you want to be in this field, you have to have the mindset for it. I agree with the others, this is NOT a homework site, rather a site to help build off the knowledge you know, so begin to actually try to write the program, and then submit it here if you're having trouble with it.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void loadNprint(int size, int a[][size]){
    int i,j,count=1,down=size-1, up =0;
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        for(j=0;j<size; j++){
            if((i%2) == 0)a[up][j] = count;
            if((i%2) == 1)a[down][j]= count;
        count++;
        }
        if((i%2) == 0)up++;//keeping track of the rows in ascending order
        if((i%2) == 1)down--;//keeping track of rows in descending order
    }
    for(i=0; i<size; i++){
        for(j=0; j<size; j++){
            printf("%4d",a[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

void main(){
    int input;
    printf("Enter a Value : ");
    scanf(" %d",&input);
    int myarray[input][input];
    loadNprint(input,myarray);
}
```

Comment: Thank u all fr the solutions. as i am new to this site i was unaware that we have to submit our code snippets too. well i have been working on this program:
    int i,j,a[50][50],k=1,m=0;
    for(i=0;i<n;i+=2)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=k;
            k++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    m=k;
    for(i=1;i<=n;i+=2)
    {
        for(j=0;j<n;j++)
        {
            a[i][j]=m;
            m++;
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    for(i=0;i<n;i++)
    {
    for(j=0;j<n;j++)
   {
     printf("%d",a[i][j]);
       }
        printf("\n");
    }
}

Answer (score -1):

This program works perfect. But if you want make some changes..do it yourself.
Next time please try some coding yourself before asking. This will print a different pattern for even numbers.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<conio.h>
int n,beginnew,cpy;
int main()
{
    printf("Please enter a value : ");
    scanf("%d",&n);

    //process
    beginnew=n-n/2+1;//beginning of new pattern
    cpy=n-1;
    for(int i=1;i<n+1;i++)
    {
        if(i<beginnew)
        {
            for(int h=n-1;h>=0;h--)
        printf("%d * ", (n*(2*i-1)-h) );
        }
        else
        {
            for(int h=n-1;h>=0;h--)
        printf("%d * ",(n*(cpy)-h) );
        cpy=cpy-2;
    }
      printf("\n");
    }
      getch();
      return 0;
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

```
//this code print Diagonal Pattern if matrix is 
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
output is :
1
4 2
7 5 3
8 6
9

    import java.util.*;
    class DiagonalPattern
    {
        public static void main(String args[])
        {
            Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
            int x[][];
            int i,j,row,col,p,temp=1,last=0;
            System.out.println("how many array wants to create and size of array");
            row=sc.nextInt();
            col=sc.nextInt();
            x=new int[row][col];
            System.out.println("Enter  " +row*col+ "  elements of array of array");
                for(i=0;i<row;i++)
                {
                for(j=0;j<col;j++)
                {
                    x[i][j]=sc.nextInt();
                    last=j;
                }
                }
            for(i=0;i<row;i++)
                {
                System.out.println("");
                int k=i;
                for(j=0;j<=i;j++,k--)
                {
                    if(j==col)
                    {
                        break;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        System.out.print(x[k][j]);  
                    System.out.print(" ");
                    }
                }
                }
            for(p=x.length;p>0;p--,temp++)
                {
                System.out.println("");
                i=x.length-1;
                int k=i;
                for(j=temp;j<=last;j++,k--)
                {
                    System.out.print(x[k][j]);  
                    System.out.print(" ");
                }
                }   
        }
    }
```

Comment: This is just a code dump, you haven't given any description of how it works. Not only that, but it's completely different to what the OP asked for. It's also in Java when the question is tagged C.